# How to start google cloud storage resumable upload?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a GCS resumable upload url on the backend, send it to the frontend to get javascript to start a big file upload directly to the bucket.

My problem, currently, is that I can't figure out how to start the upload.

All the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#start-resumable) doesn't have any code, so there is nothing for me to be based on.

My code, currently, is this:

```
def start_resumable_upload(self):
    API_ENDPOINT = (
        'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2/'
        'b%(bucket)s/o?uploadType=resumable&name=%(object_name)s'
    )
    url_params = {
        'bucket': BUCKET,
        'object_name': self.filename
    }
    headers = {
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': self.content_type,
        'X-Upload-Content-Length': 0,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    r = urlfetch.fetch(
        url=API_ENDPOINT % url_params,
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        headers=headers
    )
    return r.content
```

start_resumable_upload is a method within the file Model I created to keep track of metadata on the database, thus, self.filename will have the filename, content_type will be the mime type and so on.

The response of that request is:

**400.** That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  That’s all we know.

which is somewhat unacceptable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [google-api-python-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/)?

Comment: @jterrace yes, nowhere in the docs I'm pointed to that. let me check it out. -- how would I use to start the resumable upload?

Comment: Does BUCKET have a leading "/"? If not, your URL is malformed. You also need to authenticate the request: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing

Comment: yup, it does have a leading, it's /projectname-bucket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python/blob/master/chunked_transfer.py#L123) includes an example of doing a resumable upload in Python, using the [google-api-python-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/).

The critical setup is:

```
media = MediaFileUpload(filename, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, resumable=True)
if not media.mimetype():
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, DEFAULT_MIMETYPE, resumable=True)
request = service.objects().insert(bucket=bucket_name, name=object_name,
                                 media_body=media)
```

Comment: I took a different approach. I used signed urls, updated the GCS CORS, and uploaded the file with xhr + Blob using the PUT method. It was quite a ride...

Answer (score 3):

[This function](https://gist.github.com/bsmithyman/944c84fc38c52985e0e1762c993767d9) will generate a signed upload URL after authenticating with a file-based JSON Service Account key. This can then be returned to a client to authenticate uploads via HTTP PUT.

```
import json
import os
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2

GCP_CREDENTIALS_FILE = os.getenv('GCP_CREDENTIALS_FILE', 'client-secret.json')
GCS_UPLOAD_URL_PATTERN = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage'+ \
                         '/v1/b/{bucket}/o?uploadType=resumable'

def get_upload_url(bucket, filename, content_length, content_type='application/octet-stream',):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'client-secret.json',
        ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',),
    )
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)
    url = GCS_UPLOAD_URL_PATTERN.format(bucket=bucket)
    body = json.dumps({
        'name': filename,
    }).encode('UTF-8')
    headers = {
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': content_type,
        'X-Upload-Content-Length': content_length,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Length': len(body),
    }
    resp_headers, resp_body = http.request(url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=body)
    return resp_headers['location']
```

You could also authorize with App Engine or Compute Engine credentials. Then you would just need to change the `oauth2client` class you use to generate the `credentials` instance. If you're going to use this in production, you'll also want to add some error handling for credential problems, network issues, etc.